# Graph Homomorphism using Python

Tags: python, graph-theory, undirected-graph, homomorphism

My idea is to write a python program which would take as arguments two finite simple undirected graphs say G,H and returns the number hom(G,H) of graph homomorphisms from G to H.

Examples:
If G=K_1 (one-vertex graph) then hom(G,H) equals the number of vertices of H.
If G=K_2 (or equivalently, P_2), then hom(G,H) = 2 times the number of edges of H.

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's NP-hard. If the graph G has n vertices and the graph H has m vertices, a naive approach could be to check all n^m possible assignment functions between the two graphes.

This is equivalent to do m chained loops over `range(n)`.

I know two ways to do it in python:

1)You can generate m lists [1...n] and use `itertools.product` to get the cartesian product between these lists.

2)You can generate a string with these chained loops code and execute it in python with the `exec` built-in function.

If you use the first solution, it's highly parallelizable. So you can speed up quite a bit.

An implementation of the first idea without parallelization would be something like this:

```
from itertools import product

def verify(G, H, f):
   homomorphism = True

   for edge in G:
       if not ((f[edge[0]], f[edge[1]]) in H):
           homomorphism = False
           break

   return homomorphism

def solve(G, H, n, m):
   rangeG = [i for i in range(n)]
   assignments = list(product(rangeG, repeat=m))
   cnt = 0

   for f in assignments:
       if verify(G, H, f):
           cnt += 1

   return cnt
```

Here the graphs `G` and `H` are stored as a set of tuples. The tuples represent the edges. This representation is very convenient to test the homomorphism condition and to apply assignment functions in a fast way. The parameters `n` and `m` are the number of vertices in each graph.

For example, if you want G = S4 and H = P4 it would be something like this: `G = {(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 3), (3, 0)}` and `H = {(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)}`. Then you call the function `solve(G, H, 4, 4)`.

I tested it with some examples of the section 2.3 of [this](http://web.cs.elte.hu/%7Elovasz/hom-jarik-final.pdf) paper and it seems to be working well.

As I said, the speed can be improved a lot with parallelization. This code is parallelizable almost everywhere. It needs some testing to see what is worth to execute in parallel.

Comment: Is it know to be NP-complete, or just NP-hard? To be in NP, you'd have to find a way to count the possibly superpolynomial number of homomorphisms in polynomial time.

Comment: Oops, yes I can only confirm that it's NP-hard. Edited.

Comment: I am totally new to python, can you please assist me with the programming part? Thanks

Comment: I added some python code. Please, check my edit, @Jeff

Comment: Thanks a lot @python123  . Do I store the graphs G and H inside a driver function like this for testing ? Please have a look below:                                                                    G = {"a": {"c"},
     "b": {"c", "e"},
     "c": {"a", "b", "d", "e"},
     "d": {"c"},
     "e": {"c", "b"},
     "f": {}
     }

H = { "a" : ["d"],
      "b" : ["c", "d"],
      "c" : ["b", "f"],
      "d" : ["a", "b", "e"],
      "e" : ["d", "f"],
      "f" : ["c", "e"],
      "g" : ["c"],
      "h" : ["f"]
    }

Comment: @Jeff In my tests I stored the graphes as a set of tuples where each tuple is a pair indicating an edge. For example, if you want G = S4 and H = P4 it would be something like this: `G = {(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (0, 3), (3, 0)}` and `H = {(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)}`. Then you call the function `solve(G, H, 4, 4)`.